# getting error while using FB and Google API with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-api-php-client, google-signin

I am using FB SDK and Google API for login on my website. If I comment one API then other API works perfectly.

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

require_once '../src/fb.php';

require_once '../src/google.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['checkLogin'])){
        echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

    }
```

If I run simultaneously then got error If I run Google then got this error

```
Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required GET param "state" missing.
```

If I run FB then got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Malformed code." }
```

Can someone help me with this??

Comment: Why would you get an error containing www.googleapis.com when you use Facebook?

Comment: dont know I am new to programming :(

Comment: Then start debugging or start with something simpler

Comment: i think it is not because you are using two at one time. it is clearly saying that param state is missing from fb and malformed errod coz you are missing some param in google api or api have some invalid syntax.